# Cannot stream large files

Tags: node.js, stream

I have 2 node js servers A and B, where A connects to B to get files(large files). Here's the code which I use to handle the streams.

```
        var downloadedAmount = 0;
        stream.on('data', function (data) {
            if (Buffer.isBuffer(data)) {
                downloadedAmount += data.toString('utf8').length;
            } else {
                downloadedAmount += data.length;
            }
            if (!res.write(data)) {
                stream.pause();
            }
        });
        res.on('finish', function () {
            console.log("Finish called");
            sendUsage(reqId, downloadedAmount); // this is a async db/network call
        });
        stream.on("end", function () {
            console.log("End called");
            res.end();
        });
        res.on("drain", function () {
            stream.resume();
        });
```

It downloads files when it's only a single file which is being downloaded. My problem is when I try to download multiple files (larger than 300MB) which increases the load on the servers, the connections are closed at B and all the files are stopped at 124MB. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Update : The problem is in the B server as the direct multiple downloads (requested from browser) also tend to halt at 124MB or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Seems like the problem is altogether in a different location. I changed the Apache server settings( which the B server uses to get the files to

```
EnableSendfile On
```

Now it works.